# issue when cypress executes code asynchronously

Tags: cypress

i have this method that returns an object. if i run the code below i find that the second console.log() hits first and the object returns undefined

```
 private routeAndPassengerDataObject: undefined | RouteAndPassenger;
     public getDataFromRouteAndPassengerObject(fileName?: string): RouteAndPassenger {
        if (this.routeAndPassengerDataObject) {
          return this.routeAndPassengerDataObject;
        }

if (typeof fileName !== 'string') {
  throw new Error(`${fileName} has to be a string`);
}
cy.fixture(fileName).then((data: unknown) => {
  if (!isValidRouteAndPassengerObject(data)) {
    throw new Error(`${data} is not valid`);
  }
  console.log(`this is first`);
  this.routeAndPassengerDataObject = data;
});
console.log(`this is second`);
return this.routeAndPassengerDataObject!;


 }
}
const routeAndPassengerData = getDataFromRouteAndPassengerObject()
    console.log(routeAndPassengerData);



result-
    this is second
    this is first
undefined
```

would like to know how to handle this please.

Comment: Filip Hric has an explanation of how variables interact with the Cypress commands which is almost precisely your question. The tl;dr is that Cypress commands execute at a different time than non-Cypress code. Filip outlines a few potential solutions for the problem, and the most reasonable one seems to be adding your desired code to the Cypress chain. https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-variables

Answer (score 0):

returing the object as cypress.chainable like below has worked for me-

```
 public getDataFromRouteAndPassengerObject(fileName?: string): Cypress.Chainable<RouteAndPassenger> {
    if (this.routeAndPassengerDataObject) {
      return cy.wrap(this.routeAndPassengerDataObject);
    }

if (typeof fileName !== 'string') {
  throw new Error(`${fileName} has to be a string`);
}
return cy.fixture(fileName).then((data: unknown) => {
  if (!isValidRouteAndPassengerObject(data)) {
    throw new Error(`${data} is not valid`);
  }
  console.log(`this is first`);
  this.routeAndPassengerDataObject = data;
 return cy.wrap(this._routeAndPassengerDataObject);
});
  }
```

and then calling the object like so-

```
 const routeAndPassengerData = getDataFromRouteAndPassengerObject().then((routeAndPassenger)=>{
    console.log(routeAndPassenger)
  })
```